# Recurrence relation of an algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation, recursion

how can I know what are the recursive calls of this algorithm ?
in line two there are 2 recursive calls and I don't know how to write this as T(n) for the Recurrence relation.
Here is the algorithm :
[image]

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755

Comment: Your question is quite elementary. If you are unable to solve it on your own, I suggest reviewing course materials, and consulting with a teaching assistant or fellow student.